# How to cope with the initial null problem of the async pipe as a library developer

Tags: angular

Suppose I'm a library developer and want to publish my cool component where I have a non nullable input `data`

```
<styled-list [data]="[1,2,3,4]"></styled-list>
```

My code in the component might look like this

```
export class StyledListComponent<T> {
  @Input()
  data: ReadonlyArray<T> = [];
  
  action() {
    console.log(this.data.length);
  }
  
}
```

I don't want to focus on the initial null problem of the `async` pipe from a user perspective like [here](https://blog.lacolaco.net/2020/02/async-pipe-initial-null-problem-en/) and instead on how I as a library provider should handle this.

In the above code the user of my component passes data through using the `async` pipe and the action is triggered before the data is actually resolved I get an error.

Should I as a library developer handle these errors or is this an inherent problem of angular's async pipe that users just have to cope with?

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a template variable

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(data$ | async) as data">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of data">
        </li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Or if you don't use observables (not recommended)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data as items">
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        </li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

(You don't even need the `ng-container`, but can put it on the ul)

Comment: I'm asking how I as a component provider can provide a good solution not as a user of the component

Comment: This is for your component library. [I use it all the time](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src/lib/components/scheduler/components/scheduler/scheduler.component.html#L21)

Comment: I don't think observables are better inputs but that doesn't change the `null` problem. What you're suggesting only protects my template not the typescript code. And it's not ideal for templates either. I don't want to wrap my actual template in a deep structure of ng-containers for all my inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Internally check for null values and silently filter these out.
This can be done if using setters

```
set data(data: ReadonlyArray<T>) {
  if (data === null) {
    return;
  }
  this._data = data;
}
```

This can't be done for annotated variables though. Any access to the variable would need to perform the null check or probably the better option would be to just write a setter.

Although it does look a bit weird to be checking for existence if the typescript types don't allow null values to be passed in the first place. Other readers of the code will have to be aware of why this is done this way.